# Minimum and/or maximum list values

Tags: f#

While doing practice, I build a simple function that returns the biggest value in a list:

```
let rec findMax =        // Find maximum value in list
fun l ->
    let rec aux =
        fun l k ->
            match l with  
            | []                ->  k
            | x::xs             ->  if x >= k   then  aux xs x
                                    else aux xs k
    aux l 0
```

Meanwhile, I built a similar function to find the smallest element in a list:

```
let finMin =        //Find smallest value in list
fun l ->
    let rec aux =
        fun l k ->
            match l with
            | []        ->  k
            | x::xs     ->  if x <= k   then    aux xs x
                            else aux xs k
    aux l 0
```

Here the problem: I initialized both `aux` functions with `k = 0`. It is only partially fine: `findMax` works properly as long as no negative values are in the list. Similarly, `findMin` works well only with negative numbers.

What should be the proper value to efficiently initialize `k`? Is there a system-dependant value? Should i previously calculate it? Am I approaching the problem from the wrong side?

**P.S.** I do not use library functions to find `min` and `max` because I am learning the mechanics of the language. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Why not just start the recursion with the head value. It'll always be the min/max of a single item list. Then recurse with tail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take the first item in the list to be the min or max value and then recurse down the rest of the list comparing as you are going. For example:

```
let myMax items =
    match items with
     | [] -> failwith "no data"
     | head :: tail ->
        let rec recMax maxSoFar items =
            match items with
                | [] -> maxSoFar
                | head :: tail ->
                    if head > maxSoFar then
                        recMax head tail
                    else
                        recMax maxSoFar tail
        recMax head tail
```

Answer (score 4):

It should be `System.Int32.MaxValue` but also note you should use `System.Int32.MinValue` for `findMax` in order to make it work properly with negatives.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Even if it is perfect, solving correctly the problem, I ended with the other answer because it goes one step beyond, actually allowing me to have a better comprehension of the language. Again, thank you for your contribute.

Comment: No worries, had a look at the other answer, I think both approaches are correct, the other one is more correct from a math point of view but this one is simpler for real world computations. Another advantage of the other approach is that it's easier to generalize.