# recursive function for 2D list

Tags: f#

I'm very new to f# so please forgive my ignorance. I have a 2D list of int. I'm trying to make a function that will return another 2D list which will contain only the lowest tail items. Something like this:

```
   [[2, 3]
    [2, 4]
    [2, 5]              [[2, 3]
    [3, 8]      =>       [3, 2]
    [3, 6]               [4, 1]]
    [3, 2]
    [4, 1]]
```

I can find min value of 1D list with

```
let findMin items = 
    match items with
    | [] -> ()
    | head :: tail ->
        let rec recMin minSoFar items =
            match items with
            | [] -> minSoFar
            | head :: tail ->
                if head < minSoFar then
                    recMin head tail
                else
                    recMin minSoFar tail
        recMin head tail
```

which I copied from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47138217/minimum-and-or-maximum-list-values) answer. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I didn't understand why you wrapped a tuple inside a single element list. I think it would be better (and easier) if your input was a list of tuples: [(2,3);(2,4)...(4,1)].

Comment: What is the output you are trying to get? Is that 3 sub-lists with the smallest last value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are talking about 2D lists, but your sample input is actually a list of lists of tuples (where each list contains just a single tuple value). I assume this is a typo and you wanted to write `;` rather than `;` and create an actual 2D list:

```
let input = 
  [ [2;  3]
    [2;  4]
    [2;  5]  
    [3;  8]  
    [3;  6]  
    [3;  2]
    [4;  1] ]
```

Now, the three items that you want to get as the result seem to be the three sub-lists with the smallest last element in the list. The easiest way for obtaining those would be to sort the list of lists by the last element of sub-lists and then take top 3:

```
input 
|> List.sortBy List.last
|> List.take 3
```

This returns the three sub-lists you want, but not in the original order. If you wanted them in the original order, then you could first find the third smallest last element and then use that to filter the original list:

```
let last = 
  input 
  |> List.map List.last
  |> List.sort
  |> List.item 2

input 
|> List.filter (fun l -> List.last l <= last)
```

Note that my code does not correctly handle cases such as input smaller than 3 or empty lists, but it should give you an idea about one way of solving this problem.